# ERROR: Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Reference.ts has not been loaded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, internet-explorer-10

I get error message when I am loading my Webapp with IE10 and below IE version.

I am building an my Webapp with React 15.4.0 and firebase 5.5.0.

I have tested the Webapp with Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment line below in file "firebase-js-sdk/src/database/api/Query.ts" may help you to solve this error.

```html
 assert(__referenceConstructor, 'Reference.ts has not been loaded');
```

Other work around are also available in link below that you can try to check.

[Firebase Database (4.3.1) INTERNET ASSERT FAILED: Reference.ts has not been loaded.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/157)

Comment: Thank You for response @deepak-MSFT, But I just load the firebase CDN script so i can't able to find this file "firebase-js-sdk/src/database/api/Query.ts". Is there any other solution u have, Please give me asap.